# Eclipse: Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I have loaded an eclipse project which implements some sort of editor for petri nets. But I can't start the application because of unresolved OSGI bundles:

```
org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,
org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="1.3.0"
```

I am using **Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers** (Indigo) , is this probably the wrong version or am I still missing packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Eclipse Indigo (3.7) release is part of the old 3.x series of Eclipse releases.

The `org.eclipse.e4.xxx` plugins are part of the Eclipse 4.x releases. So you need to move to a newer release (Eclipse 4.4 Luna is the current release).

Comment: Thanks, using the latest Eclipse Version (Luna) fixed the problem :)